# Div should contain 100% height of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page I have defined three divs, left one with `col-md-2`, middle one with `col-md-8` and remaining one with `col-md-2`. And I want the right div should take the 100% screen height even if no control are there. I have set height and min-height to 100% but it is not working. My code is like this. What I need to do to overcome this.

`<div id="propertiesContainer" class="row col-md-2" style="border:solid 1px;padding-left:unset;padding-right:unset;min-height: 100%;height:100%;"></div>`

Comment: set `height: 100vh;` 1vh is 1% of screen height

Comment: add some code..

Comment: @Utpal  Does any of the answer helps you, do provide a feedback if you are having any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set body, html, container, row to 100% as well.

Note that a div will take 100% height (without any content in it) only if its parent is 100%.

```css
html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.row div{
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.row, .container{
  height:100%;
}
.row .right{
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set element's `height` to 100% of screen's height his every parent must have 100% as well.

## Example

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
}

.main .side {
  height: 100%;
}

/*/ Decoration /*/
body {
  background-color: #ffeeff;
}

.main {
  border: dashed 1px blue;
}

.main div {
  border: dashed 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container main">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    Center
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 side">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="a-class">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a-class{
    min-height: 100vh;
}

or 
.a-class{
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your code in fiddle, else may be below code help you!

```
.lastdiv{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background: #ccc;
  right:0;
}

html, body{
  height:100%;
}
```